# Configuring the search service application fails

Tags: search, 2013

I want to activate the search service on my sharepoint 2013 server via the service application management. So i add a search service application. [image: Configuration loader]

After some time, an error occurs:  [image: error]

does anyone know, how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance
Jürgen

Comment: Do you have any special characters (or accented characters) in any of the fields when creating the service application?

Comment: no, only letters

Comment: does anyone already have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the Search Service Managed Account to the WSS_ADMIN_WPG Group.

See here:
http://kancharla-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/07/the-sddl-string-contains-invalid-sid-or.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still have the same error :(

Comment: Have you tried restarting the machine or an `iisreset` after the above action?

Comment: yes - now i did but it is still not working... I made a new Account called sp_searchservice, added this acc to the farm administrators via CA after that, I followed your link and used the power shell commands. Tried to reinstall the service but the error still occurs.

Comment: I'm facing this problem too. Did you solved it? I'm spending hours. I tried going to
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\"
there I found the folder "Analytics_"+ guid. So i tried to share the folder but it still occurs

Comment: Hi! sorry i forgot to post my answer... Reinstall the server with the needed services activated... Sometimes activating services after the installation is bugged (for me).